# Why confirm() function loads before in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to know why in Chrome, this line:

```
var quer = confirm("Deseja esta poltrona?");
```

loads before the previous line:

```
imagens[i].src = "img/poltrona_selecionada.jpg";
```

On Firefox, te function works perfectly in the sequence.

This is my function:

```
function selecionarPoltrona() {
    var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0; i<poltronas.length; i++) {
        if (poltronas[i]) {
            imagens[i].src = "img/poltrona_selecionada.jpg";
            var quer = confirm("Deseja esta poltrona?");

            if (quer) {
                break;
            } else {
                imagens[i].src = "img/poltrona_disponivel.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: By "loads before", do you mean you're asking why the confirm box appears before the image does?

Comment: Exactly, it happens just on Chrome. There is a way to make the image loads before on Chrome?

Comment: no, it happens everywhere, you've just found a magic image size that makes it not happen in every browser. Image loading is async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Image object, and `<img>` element: it is not synchronous. When you tell an image what its source is, the rest of your code gets to keep running. It does not wait for the image binding to succeed, the image URL to be looked up, the data the be transfered, the bytes to be decoded, all before you *see* the image. This all happens while the rest of your code runs. However, confirm (and alert, and prompt, and all those terrible functions) don't: they block the thread. So this happens:

1. You set the image `.src` attribute, and the browser schedules this for off-thread handling. Your code continues
2. `confirm` gets triggered, and everything stops. Nothing will happen in your tab until the confirm is deal with.
3. you click through the confirm. Javascript runs again, and the browser's image source binding runs again.
4. after X amount of time, your image is done downloading, parsing, and finally renders.

If you want some code to run *after* the image finishes all its work, you do this:

```
...
img.onload = function() {
  // the code you need to have run after the image finishes loading.
}
img.onerror = function() {
  // whatever we need to do if the image cannot load.
}
img.src = "..." // trigger the image loading attempt
```

Or, using modern rather than 1998 JS:

```
...
img.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
  // the code you need to have run after the image finishes loading.
});
img.addEventListeners("error", function(evt) {
  // whatever we need to do if the image cannot load.
});
img.src = "..." // trigger the image loading attempt
```

Comment: _"everything stops"_ that's what I thought - I was just digging into the spec for a potential answer though.  [Step 6 of `confirm`](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#dom-confirm) says to "Pause", [which says](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#pause) _"If necessary, update the rendering or user interface of any Document or browsing context to reflect the current state."_ - guess that means the browser could repaint the image in that time, but probably only if the image is already cached.

Comment: all the current browsers actually just do a full halt, mostly because alert, prompt, and confirm are left-overs from an ancient flavour of JavaScript (a bit like document.write) that doesn't warrant changing how they behave - if you want a nice nonblocking modal, there's a lot of choice out there these days.

Comment: oh absolutely.  On `alert` itself - I found a while ago that that's only an _optional_ pause!  Can't say I've ever come across a browser that doesn't implement it as a blocking call though

Comment: fun fact: technically the `window` object, and any function on it, wasn't in any spec until [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object), so it's this weird mix of "obviously it needs ..." and "omg why does it still have/do ..." today =P